# Shell script equivalent to PHP $_POST

Tags: bash, shell-script, html, cgi

For example and learning purposes, I have a webpage that uses `POST` method to submit a text field. I have a server running script (bash) that I want to display what the "Query_string" is. I'm not completely familiar with PHP either, but I think `$_POST` would be used to print the submitted text. The script I am using is bash. What could I use to print out the submitted text?

Comment: See [the CGI specification](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-robinson-www-interface-00); there are environment variables defined in section 5 including `QUERY_STRING`. Post data will be on standard input. That said, a) I think this may be more of a general programming or protocol question that is off-topic here, and b) conflating the query string and post data probably isn't the best sign for how well you're going to go with this. In particular, please note that **it's very easy to write severe security holes in Bash CGI scripts**.

Comment: Make sure you have upgraded `bash` to a recent version if this machine is accessible via a network ([schellshock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29))

Answer (score 1):

As noted by the first comment, the CGI spec says that the POST data will be on standard input, encoded with the enctype specified by the form. However all methods should be supported: `multipart/form-data`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and HTML5's `text/plain`

Here's a really quick test script you can play with:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Content-type: text/plain
echo
echo Environment
printenv

echo POST contents
cat
```

The CONTENT_TYPE variable will be set to the method used for the data.

If it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, then you're going to see the classic key=value&key=value syntax, and you have to remember to URL-unescape it.

If it's `multipart/form-data`, then it's MIME, and you should watch out, there have been exploits against MIME parsers before.

If it's the new HTML5 `text/plain`, then just take the entire input from stdin as-is. This method is meant for file uploads, not form submission; you can feed the stdin file descriptor to another process safely, without having to decode URLs or MIME.

And I'd like to echo the warnings of the others here. If you aren't patched against shellshock, just letting an attacker run the CGI can be enough to exploit your system (all they have to do is override all your common shell commands, and they are bound to find one you use).